# Lock file for editing in Dropbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, dropbox-api

I am building app in iOS that saves data in Dropbox. Multiple device can use the same data. While doing this, sometime two device may overwrite same file. To avoid this situation is there any like lock file for writing.

Any alternative workaround solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Did you check the Dropbox API documentation?

Comment: @Jason Coco There is no direct way using Core APIs.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know the Dropbox API, I would always be careful with a locking mechanism. I know from some systems, that the locks lead to a problem, if for example the app crashes or quits and the lock does not get released.

A very simple approach though would be to store the modification date when you have read the file. Then, before saving changes, compare your stored value with the most current one. If they are different, the file was modified. Next ask your users how to proceed and either commit the changes, cancel or create a new file with the same name and some appendix. That is how some sync clients I use are dealing with this problem.

Comment: There is still a light chance of overwriting on others change. Say when you were checking, your last change was the final. In the short time gap between your date checking response handling and sending update to your server, others would have modified.

Comment: yes, the possibility exists, more complicated procedures might cover for that as well.